# Default values only for unset properties when deserializing

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, serialization

I have a little problem, which I'm guessing should have been solved with better code design from the beginning. But here I am.

I have an app with a pretty large user base. The app uses profiles. The profiles are are deserialized from file when starting the app.

In new releases the profile class sometimes gets new properties. If the profile is deserialized from an older version these properties will be uninitialized. Where as they will have some set default values if the profile is created with the current version of the app.

Is there a simple way of initializing a property with a default value if the serialized version doesn't have it?

Comment: It depends on the serializer

Comment: I'm doing a binary serialization, Using BinaryFormatter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify a method to run after deserializing where you could set default values:

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

[Serializable]
class Car
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Make { get; set; }
    public int Doors { get; set; }

    public string Foo { get; set; }    // added property

    ...
    [OnDeserialized()]
    internal void OnDeserializedMethod(StreamingContext context)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Foo))
            this.Foo = "Ziggy";
    }
}
```

You might want to consider ProtoBuf-NET which is a data contract binary serializer.  It is much more flexible about these things, more options, faster and creates smaller output.  I just double checked to be sure, and ProtoBuf will not undo fields it doesnt have information for.  So:

```
[ProtoContract]
class Car
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public string Make { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(3)]
    public int Doors { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(4)]
    public string Foo { get; set; }      // new prop

    public Car()
    {
        this.Foo = "Ziggy";
    }
    ...
 }
```

If there is no serialized value for `Foo`, the old value from the ctor is retained.  So you could initialize new properties there and not have to worry about them getting reset to null.  If you have a lot of properties like `Bitmap`, `Font` and `Rectangle` you might want to stay with the `BinaryFormatter`.

Comment: Thank you so much @plutonix. For now the first solution works great. For ints I just go with int? so I can check if they're nulled. But I will definitively check out ProtoBuf-NET.  Another problem I have is that sometimes I remove a property in a new version and then the serialization crashes (since it tries to set a non existing property). Maybe this could help for those situation as well?

Comment: Removing a property will be a problem...it just no longer exists.  You kinda have to leave it in the code a while.  Rather than a Nullable, you could also include a version code, and key off that to set the default for the new properties (and set the new version code). ProtoBuf uses the ID set in that attribute so if you remove Foo, as long as you dont reuse ID 4 in the near future everything is fine.